# WatiN: automate Web Page dialog

Tags: c#, watin

I use WatiN to automate my testing but how could I handle Web Page dialog window? I can connect to it but can't see source code of it.

Comment: What do you mean you want to see the source. Source code? For what?

Comment: @Ismael  
To do automation I should get page structure to handle page elements.

Comment: What kind of dialog are you working with? Why can't you attach the dialog to your instance using AttachTo<IE>?

Comment: @Emerica. This window is not IE window (there is no new iexplore process in Task Manager). Telerik handle it as Modal pop-up, not IE window. I can't handle it because source code of this window is not available. See discussion below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle popup dialog use

```
  ConfirmDialogHandler handler = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
  using (new UseDialogOnce(browser.DialogWatcher, handler))
  {
      browser.Link(Find.ByClass("Your class")).ClickNoWait(); //The action that triggers the dialog
      handler.WaitUntilExists(60);
      handler.OKButton.Click();
  }
```

Comment: In popup window I have many controls so I don't need only press OK button.

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand what is the exact problem... what buttons you have there maybe you can add a screenshot

Comment: I have such window but I cannot get its source code to automate it
http://screencast.com/t/Ovr1c54Peo

Comment: I don't believe that watin can handle sophisticated dialogs... You should use another tool to handle this. Maybe AutoIt.

Comment: You can use SendKeys in System.Windows.Forms or you can user the AutoIt api for C# search for AutoItX3Class

Comment: But how could I get page structure?

Comment: You can't :( ... If the test data will be the same between each test, you can execute script test and except for the desired result at the end. To summarize watin will not help you in this case, you should seek for another solution

Comment: I see that neither WatiN nor Selenium can't handle such case. Only Telerik can but there are some issues with it and it cost very much :(

Answer (score 1):

Use firebug in Firefox to see the Page Elements/ Dilaog Elements

Comment: I only have to use IE, because Microsoft Dynamics CRM doesn't support FF.

Comment: Use developers tools in IE8-9 (press F12 in the browser)

Comment: @alonp Dev Tools in IE don't support Web Page dialog window.

Comment: just asking for info(I have never worked with Microsoft Dynamics CRM).....Doesnt Microsoft Dynamics CRM site be run in firefox/chrome??

If its not , then probably you have to use a different solution...

Comment: @AnkushRoy As I wrote above Microsoft Dynamics CRM doesn't support FF and Chrome.